# split packaging strings using R

Tags: r, split

I'm working with some packaging strings and am in need of calculating their conversions to "each".

They look something like this:

```
     packing                          uom   
[1,] "100EA/BX 1000EA/CA"             "BX"
[2,] "100EA/CA"                       "CA"
[3,] "10EA/BX 4BX/CA"                 "EA" 
[4,] "1EA/EA"                         "BX" 
[5,] "1EA/EA 12EA/BG 12EA/DZ 94EA/CA" "BG"
```

The number of small segments range from 1 to 4. I have tried to split the cells to extract the numbers and units of measure, and then wrote a very long script with plenty of conditional statements to make the calculation. I'm wondering if there are easier ways to accomplish this task. Below is the desired output. Thanks!

```
     packing                          uom  conv 
[1,] "100EA/BX 1000EA/CA"             "BX" "100"
[2,] "100EA/CA"                       "CA" "100"
[3,] "10EA/BX 4BX/CA"                 "EA" "1"  
[4,] "1EA/EA"                         "BX" "1"  
[5,] "1EA/EA 12EA/BG 12EA/DZ 94EA/CA" "BG" "12"
```

Comment: Please show the desired output corresponding to your input. It would also be nice if your input was valid R syntax and is copy/pasteable---even if that just means adding `x <- c(` at the beginning and adding quotes and commas throughout.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. I have updated the post!

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse.

```
data <- c("12EA/DZ 36EA/BX", "10EA/BX 36EA/CA", "1EA/EA 12EA/BX 12EA/DZ 36EA/BX")

str_split(data, " ") %>%
   unlist %>% enframe(name="index", value="packing") %>%
   separate(packing, sep="/", into=c("conv", "uom"), remove=FALSE) %>%
   mutate(conv=str_replace(conv, "EA", "")) %>%
   select(packing, uom, conv)

  packing uom   conv
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>
1 12EA/DZ DZ    12
2 36EA/BX BX    36
3 10EA/BX BX    10
4 36EA/CA CA    36
5 1EA/EA  EA    1
6 12EA/BX BX    12
7 12EA/DZ DZ    12
8 36EA/BX BX    36
```